# Sharepoint 2010:  How to stop and start (restart) a service application?

Tags: service-application

In central admin, I have a list of services - excellent, and the status of each service - excellent.

Now how to I stop and start them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is under System settings => Manage services on server.

[image: Manage services on server screenshot]

Also, you can stop and start services using PowerShell.

Check out this article for comprehensive how-to on both methods:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748612.aspx